# Interpolating a Time-Series Curve using Cubic Spline

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation, cubic-spline

I have the following dataframe:

```
    M            P
2022-01-10      250
2022-04-03      100
2022-05-26      350
2022-08-01      200
   ...          ...
```

^just an example. Basically I have some dates and some prices associated with them.

I'm trying to create a *daily* time-series curve using the above fixed points with the cubic splining method.

I've looked at using the following -

```
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline

cs = CubicSpline(df['M'], df['P'])
```

But I get the following error -

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.date'
```

because it doesn't like the date variable type. Two questions:

a) Basically, how do I interpolate the x, y to produce my curve?

b) Secondly, I'm using this method to try and replicate the 'S' curve in the following documentation chart:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html

...however what I'm not them sure of is how I construct a *daily* time series with dates / calculated prices which corresponds to this curve? Will that automatically happen when the CubicSpline method is called?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Create `DatetimeIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), add missing values for daily frequency by [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) and last use [`DataFrame.interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) with method `cubicspline`:

> ‘krogh’, ‘piecewise_polynomial’, ‘spline’, ‘pchip’, ‘akima’, ‘cubicspline’: Wrappers around the SciPy interpolation methods of similar names. See Notes.

```
#convert date objects to datetimes
curve0['M'] = pd.to_datetime(curve0['M'])

df = curve0.set_index('M').asfreq('d').interpolate(method='cubicspline')
print (df)
                     P
M                     
2022-01-10  250.000000
2022-01-11  238.482096
2022-01-12  227.285579
2022-01-13  216.407317
2022-01-14  205.844180
               ...
2022-07-28  238.817308
2022-07-29  229.568679
2022-07-30  220.018338
2022-07-31  210.163156
2022-08-01  200.000000

[204 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: This works and now returns a CubicSpline object, but my question was then how do I bring this back into a *daily* time series data - preferably in a dataframe...

Comment: @SlowlyLearning - answer was changed.